# Google creates an event with a wrong time zone when the API is used

Tags: google-api, timezone, google-calendar-api, timezone-offset

When I try to save event to Google with some specific time zones, this time zones get converted to different time zones.

*e.g.*
When I use insert: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert with the following body:
[image]

---

I get wrong timezones in the response:

---

[image]

Why does Google convert it to something else?
I want to keep timezones that I chose because it looks confusing for the user.

Comment: They appear to be resolving links/aliases to canonical zones. [See the list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). `Canada/Saskatchewan` is an alias for `America/Regina`.  Does it really matter?

Comment: Users select a timezone, save it and then they are shocked by different time zone being shown... So as I understand one timezone has many links and once it's saved to Google we lose the exact link. So, it becomes ambiguous to find a link?

Comment: Understood.  I'm not sure why Google Calendar decided to do that, so I can't answer the direct "why" question. Can you retain it locally in your own code?

Comment: Only in case I save this information locally. Because once it's stored in Google, the information about what timezone link was chosen is lost.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
I think the that timezone has been deprecated and not supported by Google Calendar.

[image]

Per the docs the timezone is IANA, and that timezone has been deprecates

[image]

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Also **Canada/Saskatchewan** is supposed to be -06:00, why is it plus +03:00 in your json request?

Lastly, I don't see Canada/Saskatchewan in the available Google Calendar Timzones.

[image]